# Devexpress Winforms Gridview RowSelection Checkbox in intermediate state

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, checkbox, devexpress

I'm using WinForms Devexpress and bumped into the following task:
Somehow I need for DevExpress GridView to programmatically set data row selection checkbox to intermediate state (as the state of the top checkbox at the header at the picture below:

[image]

I'm wondering if it is possible or how to overcome the issue.

Comment: Is this the filter you are trying to reset or the contents of an actual check box?

Comment: Do you use RepositoryItemCheckEdit in that column?

Comment: hambone, It was for content of check box.

Marko Juvančič, Yep. I resolved the problem using RepositoryItemCheckEdit.

Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the column editor's `AllowGrayed` property to `true`.

```
this.yourBooleanColumn.ColumnEdit = this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1;    
this.repositoryItemCheckEdit1.AllowGrayed = true;
```